# std::string doesn't recognize character greater then 127

Tags: c++, string, qt, qbytearray, qtserialport

I've made a tansmition with a ascii code style and everything was ok until I made crc check. In my project crc is a one byte. In my reciver i put everything into std::string and if crc is smaller then 127 everything is ok. But if my crc is grater then 127 then to my std::string is add addtional data - example below.

```
if crc = 80 -> in std:string "P"
if crc = 168 -> in std::string "ï¿½" (three diffrent signs)
```

What am I doing wrong? I thought that there are special character above the 127, but now I'm lost...

EDIT:
I've tried to make it simple, but of course I can give u code :).

```
QSerialPort *serial = new QSerialPort;
std::string *buffer = new std::string;
//when 'readyRead' event comes from serial then:
QString tempBuffer = serial->readAll();
*buffer += tempBuffer.toStdString();
```

Then in diffrent thread I work on the buffer data. The problem is when I sending a byte which is bigger then 127 - in that situation some additional character are appended to my buffer (like in the first example).

Comment: Can you show your code? It is unclear what you are writing.

Comment: Thanks for the update. Are you sure you are using 8 data bits and not 7? What does the dataBits property contain?

Comment: Also, mind you that that QIODevice write interface is char which is compiler dependent. It can be signed as well as unsigned. Also, please do not allocate std::string on the stack. Moreover, do not even use it in this scenario. Just use QByteArray. You are reading into a QString which will make the default conversion (latin1?), so if you want unicode, you have to make the fromUtf8 call on the result of the read again, but then again: this mess could be eliminated by dropping std::string and using raw QByteArray. Does that help with figuring out the issue? It is still a bit unclear to me..

Comment: Ok - I found my mistake. I implicitly casted from QByteArray to QString and QString did all the mess. Now I use QByteArray and simple method data() which return char* and everything is ok. :D thanks for help.

Comment: @LaszloPapp "please do not allocate std::string on the stack" - I assume you meant *heap*?

Comment: @lethal-guitar: yep, I got that right in the answer, but not in the comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
QString tempBuffer = serial->readAll();
*buffer += tempBuffer.toStdString();
```

1) You are relying on the default conversion from QByteArray to QString which is utf-8 as opposed to local latin 1 if that is what you want.

> [QString::QString(const QByteArray & ba)](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qstring.html#QString-9)
>
> Constructs a string initialized with the byte array ba. The given byte array is converted to Unicode using fromUtf8(). Stops copying at the first 0 character, otherwise copies the entire byte array.

You will need to call [fromLatin1](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qstring.html#fromLatin1) explicitly in that case on the return value of readAll, i.e.:

```
QString tempBuffer = QString::fromLatin1(serial->readAll());
qDebug() << tempBuffer;
```

Your requirement could also be local 8 bit related, in which case you would do something similar but with [fromLocal8Bit](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qstring.html#fromLocal8Bit).

2) It is bad idea to allocate memory for the std::string object on the heap. It is meant to be a stack object.

3) In this scenario, the code will be much simpler if you drop the std::string internal data handling altogether because then you can also drop QString for the general operation and you can keep that only for data display. That way, you could also get the "raw c data" with the [data() method](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qbytearray.html#data).

There are some things to keep in mind when dealing with character data over 127, namely:

4) You need to have 8 data bit set for the property which is the default these days, but you need to make sure it is not 7 bits.

5) The QIODevice interface deals with char* type for reading and writing, and that is compiler dependent whether it is signed or unsigned. So long as you handle them consistently on the receiver and sender sides, this will not be an issue though.

Answer (score -2):

You can try using wstring and perhaps change your character set.

Comment: Why should he try that? What effect would that have? What is the underlying problem this solves? How should he do this? At the moment this reads more like a comment than an answer.

Comment: I upvoted this post because two unexplained downvotes are very unfair to say the least and it feels like a different approach trying to solve the issue. For the record, Bart told to me in chat he is not the downvoter, so that may help avoiding some needless comment argument. The two people should consider being more collaborative with providing actual feedback to someone who is trying to help and hence increase the value of the site. It is possible that this answer is enough for the OP without further explanation.